# No. of Mongodb instances on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

IS there a way that we can calculate how many 'mongod' instances are running on a single ubuntu server at a given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu, the `ps` output of a running `mongod` process will look something like this -

mongodb   2210  3.3  1.5 259012 15300 pts/0    Dl   11:48   0:00 mongod --dbpath /var/tmp/mongotest --logpath /var/tmp/mongotest_log --port 3001

so you can follow Sergio's solution. If you want to exclude the config server element (as it's a mongod process also, see my comment)

Another way of checking would be to run -

```
ls /etc/mongodb*conf | wc -l
```

as each mongod instance **should** (if it's installed as per recommended) its own configuration file under `etc`, e.g. /etc/mongodb.conf, /etc/mongodb1.conf, /etc/mongodb2.conf etc.

Each mongod instance will have its own logpath and datapath, which you should find configured in the relevant configuration file under `etc`. For example -

```
# mongodb1.conf

dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb1

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb1.log

port = 30001
```

so the previous command will also apply.

```
ls /var/lib/mongodb* | wc -l

ls /var/log/mongodb/mongodb*log | wc -l
```

You may be interested in my answer on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19067/upstart-script-in-ubuntu-for-mongodb) for more information on how to run multiple mongodb instances on Ubuntu using Upstart.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use some unix-fu.

```
ps aux | grep mongod | grep -v grep |  wc -l
```

The `grep -v grep` part is to exclude grep self-match. If someone knows a better solution, please improve.

Comment: If (s)he's looking for pure mongod instances, then we might want to exclude the mongod config server process also - "ps aux | grep mongod | egrep -v 'grep|configsvr' |  wc -l". Not sure why your last answer was downvoted!

Comment: I have no idea either. +1'd yours :)